# Get paypal access token in android with cURL

Tags: android, api, curl, paypal, httpurlconnection

Please im trying to get Paypal access token by making a call to the paypal api endpoint, ive tried several codes and end up with several errors the most recent is throwing an **error 401 with response message Unauthorized**

This is the code im using

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
try{
    client = "AdmXhYPBHuOBiA16LJQGNLfzlyQ6hAU8-jwCsWIzZ97wAj2DAB_z";
    secret = "EKdd4-qSMmcwduoI_FI4ZBfj-6BsNDZD8aJm1yni_ML7Cy";
    String tokenInput = "grant_type=client_credentials";
    URL url = new URL("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    
            String up = secret + ":" + client;
    
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64().encode(up.getBytes())));
       
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en_US");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
    textview1.setText("Response code:" + conn.getResponseCode());
    textview2.setText("Response message:" + conn.getResponseMessage());
}catch(Exception e){
    textview3.setText(e.toString());
}
```

I think the Problem is coming from **grant_type=client_credentials** as i do not know how to pass it into my code when making the request to the api

Answer (score 0):

A PayPal API `secret` *does not* belong in a client-side Android or web Application.

API secrets should only be used from a server that only you have control over.

It seems you are *actually* looking for the [Native Checkout SDK for Android](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/).

Comment: i know and the API secret i used in the code above is incomplete and I just generated. Im not looking for the Native SDK for Android, im looking for a way to connect to the API directly that way i have more control.

Comment: All im asking for is a way to get my access token using client id & secret key directly from Android

Comment: And my answer is you should never do this. Direct connections using a client and secret should never be done from client-side code.